For any two points x,y in compact metric space $(M,\rho)$ we have z in M : $\rho(x,z)=\rho(x,y)/2$, show there is u in M : $\rho(x,u)=\rho(x,y)/3$
Here is my attempt at a solution. Could anyone advise about the validity or points of improvement?
The core of the proof relies on generating a sequence of midpoints given the two starting points $x$ and $y$ and their midpoint, $z$. Generate a midpoint between $x$ and $z$, call it $z_1$ then another between z and $z_1$ call it $z_2$ etc.
\begin{equation*}\rho(x,z) = \rho(z,y) = \frac{\rho(x,y)}{2}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\exists z_{1} \in M : \rho(x,z_{1}) = \rho(z_{1},z) = \frac{\rho(x,z)}{2} =\frac{\rho(x,y)}{4} \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\exists z_{2} \in M : \rho(z,z_{2}) = \rho(z_{1},z_{2})=\frac{\rho(z_{1},z)}{2}=\frac{\rho(x,z)}{4} = \frac{\rho(x,y)}{8} \end{equation*}
$\implies$
\begin{equation*}\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \ with\ \ k\ge 0, \ \exists z_{k+1} \in M : \rho(z_{k},z_{k+1}) =\frac{\rho(x,z)}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{\rho(x,y)}{2^{k+2}}\ \ \ ...(\dagger)
\end{equation*}
Where $z_{0}$ is taken to equal $z$ in the case of $k=0$.
Using this sequence to generate a distance relationship between $x$ and the $z_{n^{th}}$ point;
$For\ n\ge 1\ and\ z_{0} = z,$
\begin{equation*}\rho(x,z_{n}) = \rho(x,z) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\rho(z_{k},z_{k+1})(-1)^{k+1}.
\end{equation*}
By ($\dagger$) above
and $\rho(x,z) = \frac{\rho(x,y)}{2}$ it holds that,
$For\ n\ge 1\ and\ z_{0} = z,$
\begin{equation*}\rho(x,z_{n}) =\frac{\rho(x,y)}{2}  + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\rho(x,y)}{2^{k+2}}(-1)^{k+1}\\ =\ \rho(x,y) \sum_{k=0}^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}(-1)^{k}.
\end{equation*}
Letting $S_{n}$ be the $n^{th}$ partial sum of this series, taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ yields,
\begin{equation*} \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n} = \rho(x,y) \sum_{k=0}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}(-1)^{k} = \frac{\rho(x,y)}{3}.
\end{equation*}
Let $u =  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} z_{n}$  then,
\begin{equation*} \rho(x,y) = \rho(x,u) + \rho(u,y)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*} \rho(x,y) = \frac{\rho(x,y)}{3} + \rho(u,y)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*} \frac{2}{3}\rho(x,y) = \rho(u,y).
\end{equation*}

The idea looks correct to me: you generate a sequence of points whose distance to $x$ converges to $\rho(x,y)/3$. Note, however, that you need compactness to claim that a convergent subsequence of $z_n$ exists, and if you let $u$ be its limit you can show that $\rho(x,u)=\rho(x,y)/3$.

Ignore my previous comment, you do already show that $z_n$ is Cauchy (and compact implies complete).

Why is it okay to use the metric here as having the property $d(a,b)=d(a,c)+d(c,b)$
